# python - Retrieving Non English Text from MS SQL

Tags: python, unicode, pyodbc

I am trying to retrieve non-english data from MS SQL Server using python pyodbc module.

The non-english text looks like following

```
\u0905\u0939\u092e\u0926\u0928\u0917\u0930
```

I am writting an API layer, in which I will send the same text in `json` format. I am expecting data to be shown in a way like

```
अहमदनगर
```

**Do I  need to configure something in pyodbc, so that the data will be shown correctly?**

My pyodbc connection string is

```
mssql+pyodbc://user:password@machine/Database?charset=utf8
```

Thanks
Aniruddha

Comment: what version of pyodbc are you using?  What version of python?  What platform are you running on?

Comment: Windows 7 64 bit. Python 2.7.6 pyodbc 3.0.7

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure that your source file is encoded as UTF-8. The following code works for me:

```python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import pyodbc

connStr = (
    r'Driver={SQL Server};' +
    r'Server=127.0.0.1,52865;' +
    r'Database=myDb;' +
    r'Trusted_Connection=Yes;'
    )
db = pyodbc.connect(connStr)
sql = "SELECT word FROM vocabulary WHERE ID=1"
cursor1 = db.execute(sql)
while 1:
    row = cursor1.fetchone()
    if not row:
        break
    print row.word
cursor1.close()
db.close()
```

Note the coding hint in the first line. The result that appears in the Python shell (IDLE) is

```
你好
```